# Function that verifies if a person exists[comparing strings in C]

Tags: c, arrays, string

The follow snippet of code is a function that I use in a C program in order to verify that the client does not exist before the user can make a new reservation. Clients are being stored in a 2-D array [`clients[NAME][SURNAME]`) .

Inside the function that adds new clients I call the following function[`findPerson`]  that returns a Boolean, if the client exists or no.

The approach that I've tried to implement is the following.

**1** . Find the character of the client that coincides with the first character of the new insertion.

**2.** If that happens, begin to count the letters of the already-registered client.

**3.**  If the counted letters coincide with the length of the new client, then the client already exists, return true.

**4.** Else, move on to the next letter of the already-registered client and check again.

**5.** If we reach to the end of the already-registered client we move to the next registered client.

**6.** Return false if all clients have been checked and no match has been found.

Here's the code, which always returns false , even when I'm adding clients with same name.

```
bool findPerson(char *newClient, char clients[NAME][SURNAME],int clientIndex )               
{

 int i, c, k, counter ;

 counter = 0;
 c = 0 ; 

 printf("We are searching if %s exists \n",newClient) ;

 for(k = 0; k < clientIndex ;){                                 /*for-each client*/
    for(i = 0 ; i !='\0' ;)
    {
      if( newClient[0] == clients[k][i] ){                 
         while( (newClient[c] == clients[k][counter]) && (c != '\0') ){
           counter++;
            c++;
         }

         if(strlen(newClient) == counter ){
              return true ;   
         }

         else{
             i++;
             counter = 0 ;
         }
       }
    }

    k++;
 }

return false ;
}
```

Comment: In terms of design a 2D array of NAME and SURNAME seems very odd.  Why not a one dimensional array of a struct that contains name and surname?  This makes more sense and simplifies your handling of arrays.  And why not something like `strcmp` and be more or less done with it?

Comment: I agree totally with you about using a struct, I would have used it but it's the specification of the assignment. The clients have to be stored in a 2-D array. As for the `strcmp` function you're right also, I wil give it a try and edit soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i = 0 ; i !='\0' ;)
```

The `\0` character evaluates to a numerical zero in this context. The check will be performed as soon as the loop begins, after `i` is assigned to zero, instantly fail and thus will never do any actual processing.